# Haskell recursive counting

Tags: haskell, recursion, count

I just started learning Haskell (I'm trying to make a mastermind solver).

I have to count how many times one color from a lists occurs in another list:

```
reaction [Green, Purple, Green, Green] [Purple, Green, Blue, Yellow] 0
```

Would have to give me the result "2", Because "Green" from list 1 occurs 1 time in list 2, and the same goes for "Purple". So I've written a little piece of code:

```
reaction [] ys n = n
reaction (x:xs) ys n = foldr (\y _ -> if x == y then reaction (filter' x xs) ys n + 1 else reaction xs ys n + 0) n ys

filter' c xs = filter(\x -> x /= c) xs
```

It takes the head X from list 1 and compares it to every element in list 2, if it is the same it will filter all the values from list 1 which are corresponding to X (so it won't count any duplicates) and add + 1 to "N". However it gives me the result "1", and I really can't seem to find out why... I hope anyone can help me!
Steven

Comment: What is `reaction''`? What is the type of `Green`, `Purple`, etc.?

Comment: reaction is an Int, and Green etc are Colors

Comment: No, I mean: what is `reaction''` (`reaction` followed by two single quotes)? It's not defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: Oh sorry, that's a typo, it meant to be the recursive part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you throw away the second argument (the *accumulator*) of the function that you pass to `foldr`:

```
foldr (\y _ -> ...
```

I can't think of a use case of `foldr` where you would want to do that.

Your question seems to stem from a misunderstanding of `foldr`. Are you sure you understand what this function does? If you have any doubt, read, for instance, [this section of the Wikipedia page on folds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Folds_as_structural_transformations); you should find the diagram explaining what a right fold is particularly illuminating.

If I correctly understand what you want to do, the following approach should do the job:

```
import Data.List

data Color = Blue | Green | Purple | Yellow
  deriving Eq

reaction :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int -> Int
reaction xs ys n = foldr (\x acc -> length (filter (== x) ys) + acc) n $ nub xs
```

For information, the [`nub`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#nub) function takes a list and returns a list formed by removing all duplicates element from it; it is exported by the [`Data.List` module](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html).

#### Test in GHCi:

```
λ> reaction [Green, Purple, Green, Green] [Purple, Green, Blue, Yellow] 0
2
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `filter'` is just `filter (/= x)`.

From your description of the problem, a clearer way to write this (at least initially) is

```
reaction [] ys n = n
reaction (x : xs) ys n | x `elem` ys = reaction (filter (/= x) xs) ys (n+1)
                       | otherwise = reaction xs ys n
```

This doesn't appear to be a simple fold to me because the list you are iterating over (`xs`) changes as you iterate over it.